# Could not find gem tzinfo-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created new app however I cannot run the server because of the error on screenshot(full image url: http://oi60.tinypic.com/xmqtr5.jpg).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You need to type ``bundle install`` or just ``bundle`` in your console (as it is said on the error BTW!)

Comment: https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html @dgilperez OP did; that’s a certificate issue.

Comment: I tried to bundle-install and I got this error: http://tinypic.com/r/20711ti/8

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. Opened gemfile and changed to HTTP form HTTPS         https://rubygems.org/ ---> http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type on your command prompt :

```
bundle
```

this work for me.

[image: pic]